# how to check @DocumentUniqueID?

Tags: lotus-domino

I have a field empID which needs to be unique...
 I wrote the following code-

```
mAns := @DbLookup( "" : "NoCache" ; @DbName ; "lkpEmpMasterbyEmpCode"
; empId ; "empName");

@If(empId = "";@Failure("ID cannot be empty.");@IsError(mAns); "ERROR";mAns != ""; @Failure("Employee ID already exists. Please enter a unique 
value.");@Success);
```

but the issue is that when I try to edit any document then the empID is checked again for uniqueness and it throws an error that empID already exists...and thus I cannot edit any doc...

i want to have a code where I can compare the `@DocumentUniqueID` OF the existing doc with the editing doc and if same then empID should not throw error if same...

can someone help.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If empID will never change after the document is created, you can qualify the validation formula with @IsNewDoc to prevent execution after the document has been saved:

```
@If(@IsNewDoc; 
    [validation formula here]; 
    @Success
)
```

If empID might change after the document is created, you can use the [RETURNDOCUMENTUNIQUEID] keyword for @DBLookup to retrieve the value for comparison:

```
mAns := @DbLookup( "" : "NoCache" ; @DbName ; "lkpEmpMasterbyEmpCode"
; empId ; "empName"; [RETURNDOCUMENTUNIQUEID]);
```

Other options would include: 1) a computed field on the document with the formula @Text(@DocumentUniqueID) that could be the target field for your @DBLookup or 2) a column in your lookup view with the column formula @Text(@DocumentUniqueID) that could be the target for your lookup.

Comment: Beware of [ReturnDocumentUniqueID] if you are using anything earlier than Notes 6.5.5, due to the issue described in this technote: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21201399  And note that it can crash servers in addition to the Notes client.  I had an agent crashing because it was doing a ComputeWithForm call against a form that had a field containing [ReturnDocumentUniqueID].

Comment: ReturnDocumentUniqueID looks very scary now.